# SQL Server 2005: how can I return a datetime variable in MMDDYYY format?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to return today's date in `MMDDYYY` format (I do not want the time) using SQL Server 2005.

I've tried using convert but I get the following error:

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

This is the SQL code:

```
declare @OldDate datetime;
declare @ConvertedDate datetime;

set @OldDate= getdate();
set @ConvertedDate= convert (varchar,@OldDate,103)

print @ConvertedDate
```

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks Lori

Comment: keep this chart for reference - http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store a `varchar` in a `datetime` variable.  It should be

```
declare @OldDate datetime;
declare @ConvertedDate varchar(50);

set @OldDate = getdate();
set @ConvertedDate = convert(varchar(50), @OldDate, 103)

print @ConvertedDate
```